# "Invalid parameter(s): attributes" issue in context of "blocks.registerBlockType" filter

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor

**The goal**

I'm working on a plugin that adds classes and attributes to any block.

On the frontend the blocks are animated using JS and CSS.

**It basically works, but...**

It seemed to be working fine with all blocks (haven't tested all), but when I added a "Tag Cloud" block to a page I got the following `400 error`:

[image]

In the console I found the `params  Object { attributes: "blockAnimationClass is not a valid property of Object." }` response.

I use the following filter to add the properties:

```
function addAnimationOptions(settings, name) {
    if (typeof settings.attributes !== 'undefined') {
        settings.attributes = Object.assign(settings.attributes, {
            blockAnimationClass: {
                type: 'string',
                default: ''
            }
        });
    }
    return settings;
}
    
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'ekesto/add-animation-options',
    addAnimationOptions
);
```

In the `InspectorControls` sidebar I have a `SelectControl` that contains class names that I add to the save function via the `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter:

```
function animationOptionsApplyExtraClass(extraProps, blockType, attributes) {
    const { blockAnimationClass } = attributes;
    if (typeof blockAnimationClass !== '' && blockAnimationClass) {
        let children_classes = '';
        switch(blockAnimationClass) {
            case 'anim-slide-children-up':
                children_classes = 'anim-slide-up';
                break;
            default:
                children_classes = '';
                extraProps.className = extraProps.className + ' animation-observer ' + blockAnimationClass;
        }
        // if a children animation is selected, add classes
        if (children_classes != '') {           
            children_classes += ' animation-observer';
            extraProps['data-anim-children'] = children_classes.trim();
        }
    }
    return extraProps;
}
    
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'ekesto/animation-options-apply-class',
    animationOptionsApplyExtraClass
);
```

**Question**

In what way is the `Tag Cloud` block different?

Am I doing some no-go stuff here, or what detail am I missing?

Is it linked to the issue that my attributes are not available when the block is rendered first? If so, is there a filter that adds the attributes at an earlier stage?

Appreciate any hint!

Comment: the error message is telling you that the tag cloud does not have an attribute of that name, but it found one, so something must be wrong. Eitherway this isn't the approach you should take, blocks already have a class attribute that can be used for this so adding an additional attribute is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I store the classes into the default `className` property, besides the optional `extraProps['data-anim-children']` property that is being used as a data attribute that is handled using JS.. Sally's suggestion removed the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In what way is the `Tag Cloud` block different?

That block is a [dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/), which [uses a *live rendering*](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/87e7260bc3eca87366e610163490d96c94bd0575/packages/block-library/src/tag-cloud/edit.js#L170-L174) using `ServerSideRender`, and the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-server-side-render/#api-endpoint) stated that "*If you pass attributes to `ServerSideRender`, the block must also be registered and have its attributes **defined in PHP***", therefore, custom attributes for the block must be defined in PHP as well and not just JavaScript.

To fix the issue, you can use the [`register_block_type_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_block_type_args/) to add the `blockAnimationClass` attribute. E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'register_block_type_args', 'my_add_custom_block_type_attributes' );
function my_add_custom_block_type_attributes( $args ) {
    $args['attributes']['blockAnimationClass'] = array(
        'type'    => 'string',
        'default' => '',
    );

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense.. I managed to get rid of the error by using the filter. This answered my question!

Comment: Now the next issue is, that the CSS classes are correctly added in the editor (when selecting an animation type), but they don't seem to be saved (as they are not rendered frontend).. Somehow the `core/tag-cloud` doesn't show up in the `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter. Could this be linked? Weirdly enough I do get the attribute value (containing the class name of the selected animation) when doing a `var_dump` of the `$block` parameter in a `render_block` filter in PHP.. Should you have a hint on that, I'd really appreciate!

Comment: They're not saved because it's a dynamic block which does not add anything to the post content, apart from the block comment delimiter markup. So I'd use `editor.BlockEdit` and *not* `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps`, to modify the `className` *attribute*. As for the `data-anim-children` *prop* though, is it actually necessary, i.e. can't you just modify the block content/markup based on the `blockAnimationClass` value? But if it's necessary, then (for dynamic blocks with a `render_callback`) you can use the PHP filter hook to add that `data` attribute.

Comment: "*to modify the block content/markup*" - or more precisely, to apply the animation based on the element's classes. And if this is a JS-based animation, then you can use JS on the front-end to add the `data` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for your time and energy! Your inputs lead to some more research and I optimized my code. I'm now setting the class into the official `className` attribute - where it belongs. And the `data` attribute is now set in the `render_block` hook, as disabling the plugin would lead to block recovery issues when they're stored as an `extraProps` (like I did before). After oh so many block tutorials the bigger picture is slowly put together in my brain :) Piece by piece.. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, I would simply modify the `className` attribute, but I posted this answer basically just so that you know what happened  anyway, happy coding and all the best!